# MAMP crashes on launch

Tags: crash, mamp, hosts

I've got a problem quite annoying I cannot sort out.

I am running MAMP as a localhost server. Everything was working perfectly until I had the (maybe stupid) idea to modify my `/private/etc/hosts` file in order to add a domain name to my IP address.

In addition to be unable to add this domain name I am now faced with a crash when I try to open the MAMP software, more precisely with the famous

> "the program has unexpectedly finished"

It seems that there is a problem with the configuration since an other error message appears and disappears very quickly after I click "ignore" or "restart" but I don't have time to read it. I try to uninstall (and reinstall) MAMP but as it could be expected the problem is still there.

I don't know what to do since it still goes wrong even after I change the `hosts` file as it was before my first modification (or at least as I think it was before).

Does anybody could help me to fix this problem?

EDIT:
Just in case this could help, this is the content of my current hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

what is the message when you launch MAMP with command line ? /Applications/MAMP/MAMP.app/Contents/MacOS/MAMP

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience but it has been fixed I don't know how. Maybe there was something else interferring with the port? After several rebootings the problem has disappeared. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Again it crashes. Here is the message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[_NSPlaceholderData initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]: nil URL argument' . I don't know why URL is nil